# PanoramaGL library for android studio

Tags: android-studio, 360-panorama

I have a developed app using PanoramaGL library from this [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/panoramagl-android/downloads). But it is for Eclipse and I want it for Android Studio because the eclipse project is building successfully in Android Studio but it is not running. Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the library in your build.gradle file ?

There is no difference between Libraries in Eclipse and Android Studio. Just be aware that Android Studio uses Gradle as its build system.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/PanoramaGL_0.2-beta.jar')
...
}
```